# Template as a parameter of function template - deduction fail

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I want to create template like this which can deduce TT class template an T type:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template < template <typename> class TT, typename T>
T f(TT<T*> & A ){
    cout << "it works\n";
    return *A[0];
};


int main(){
    vector<int*> v;
    f(v);
    return 0;
}
```

I have an error (with clang-4.0):

```
temded2.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
temded2.cpp:20:21: error: no matching function for call to ‘f(std::vector<int*>&)’
     f<std::vector>(v);
                     ^
temded2.cpp:12:3: note: candidate: template<template<class> class TT, class T> T f(TT<T*>&)
 T f(TT<T*> & A ){
   ^
```

I think that TT should be equal to std::vector and T should be equal to int, what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your template template-parameter isn't what you think it is. There's more to a `std::vector<T>` than you think, including default template parameters that you're not accounting for. Luckily, variadic arguments in C++11 will help you solve that problem

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template < template <typename, typename...> class TT, typename T, typename... Args>
T f(TT<T*, Args...> & A )
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
    if (A.size() > 0)
        return *(A[0]);
    return T();
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int*> v;
    f(v);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
T f(TT<T *, Args...> &) [TT = vector, T = int, Args = <std::__1::allocator<int *>>]
```

Note the `Args` above. Because those are missing in your very *specific* template template-parameter expected arg list, there is no match. As you can see, variadic arguments can solve that problem.

Comment: Thank you, works when i have: template < template <typename, typename...> class TT, typename T>  don't need third parameter.

Comment: @peterSweter Glad it helped. I included the variadic argument to demonstrate with g++/clang++ pretty-function feature what is really be instantiated with your call from `main()`. Glad it makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

[`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is a class template that takes two template parameters:

```
template<
    class T,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<T>
> class vector;
```

Your `f` expects a class template with only one template parameter. So it simply doesn't match.

Answer (score 2):

Since vector is a template with two template parameter, one  for the type of the elements, and one for the allocator,

```
template<
    class T,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<T>
> class vector;
```

Your temlate parameter B also needs two template parameters, so the function looks like this:

```
template <template <typename, typename> class V, typename T, typename A>
T f(V<T, A>& arg ){
    cout << "it works\n";
    return arg[0];
};
```

Now the function works.
[live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/uRbhFPI8yKUc7Eag)